# Not permitted to create a new directory on a ntfs partition?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, partitioning, filesystems, ntfs

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. When I open a pdf file in Evince, and want to click "Save as" in the menu of Evince to create a new directory on a ntfs partition (shared between Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7 installed on the same hard drive but different partitions) and save the file there, sometimes I am able to create a new directory, and sometimes I am not because it says

> The folder could not be created
>
> "Error creating directory: Permission denied"

But I can always create a new directory under EXT4 partition created when installing Ubuntu.

I was wondering how I can create a new folder on that shared ntfs partition, when going through Evince?

Comment: Are the partitions and PDF files all owned by the same user?

Comment: yes. Sometimes, i have the permission, and sometimes I don't. It is not stable.

Comment: Here's a link to another discussion about this. It looks like this is a bug. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112085/sometimes-dont-have-permission-to-create-new-folders-on-an-ntfs-partition-in-ev

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `fstab` file and add add the `gid=1000` to allow all the users in your group to have rights on the partition or else you can use the `uid=1000` so only your user has privileges on it. The `fstab` file is located at `/etc/fstab` and you can edit such options with the `gnome-disks-manager` app. Reboot or issue the `mount -a` command as root to apply changes to fstab.